# Mounting NFS stopped working after server upgrade to newest Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, nfs, mount

I have NFS server that is working as a general filer in a LAN.

Recently due to disk malfunction, I lost everything there, so I got new disks, reinstalled newest Debian (jessie), copied back config files - and NFS no longer works?!

my /etc/exports contains:

```
/media/media *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=31244,anongid=31451)
/media/private *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=16830,anongid=10818)
```

I did couple of reboots, /etc/init.d/nfs-common restart, /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restarts.

On client side, I have, in /etc/fstab:

```
172.28.173.1:/media/media                  /media/MEDIA      nfs     rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,soft,intr,rw,user,noatime,nodiratime  0       0
172.28.173.1:/media/private                /mnt/nfs/private  nfs     rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,soft,intr,rw,user,noatime,nodiratime  0       0
```

When mounting the filesystem, mount command takes long time, and ends without printing anything. Running "df" later on shows:

```
df: ‘/media/MEDIA’: Stale NFS file handle
```

In syslog on client I see:

```
2013-12-18T15:27:08.319605+01:00 h3po4 kernel: [  363.398977] RPC: AUTH_GSS upcall timed out.
2013-12-18T15:27:08.319619+01:00 h3po4 kernel: [  363.398977] Please check user daemon is running.
```

But I have no idea what daemon it talks about, why it even needs some "user daemon", and why is there AUTH_GSS call - I want access to be 100% open to the nfs share within LAN.

I verified that it's not a firewall issue (by disabling firewall for a test).

I don't think I ever reconfigured anything else on the server, before disk crash, but I'm not sure - the machine has been working for > 4 years, without a problem, so I could have changed something and forgot about it.

So, I checked some more things.

Before mounting on client, mount directory is:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 maj  1  2013 MEDIA/
```

But after "mount /media/MEDIA", waiting for it to finish, I get:

```
ls: cannot access /media/MEDIA: Stale NFS file handle
d?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? MEDIA/
```

The directory on server side is always "normal":

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 media media 6 Dec 18 14:05 /media/media/
```

also, exportfs works fine:

```
=# exportfs -v
/media/media        <world>(rw,wdelay,root_squash,all_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=31244,anongid=31451,sec=sys,rw,root_squash,all_squash)
/media/private      <world>(rw,wdelay,root_squash,all_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=16830,anongid=10818,sec=sys,rw,root_squash,all_squash)
```

and I can see the exported filesystems from client:

```
$ showmount -e blob
Export list for blob:
/media/private *
/media/media   *
```

Comment: You accidentally the whole question.

Comment: Sorry - problem with firefox, unrelated :)

Comment: What is the contents of /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server ?

Comment: Can you confirm rpcbind is running and that your iptables allow connections to rpcbind?

Does your client kernel support the nfs version being used by your nfs server?

Comment: All seemed to be working. Got a guy on IRC to help me by adding ",fsid=2" to options for /media/media, and ",fsid=3" to options for /media/private. Afterwards, I can actually mount the filesystems, though it takes ~ 15 seconds for the first mount to work.